# Using AWS glue it is ending up as an insert into the table instead of an update

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-dms, aws-lake-formation

I've DMS configured to continuously replicate data from my source database to S3.
This creates CDC CSV file. I have the following the sample output

```
OP   ID   DESCRIPTION
I    1    INSERT RECORD
U    1    UPDATE THE RECORD
```

After DMS is running properly, I trigger an AWS Glue Crawler to build the Data Catalog for the S3
Bucket that contains the Replication file.
Loading data from S3 to RDS using AWS Lake Formation, it is inserted into the table in both rows instead of an update.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you update your question with an expected result and what you get now?

Comment: OP   ID   DESCRIPTION
I       1    INSERT RECORD
U     1    UPDATE THE RECORD

Comment: above 2 records are loading and both are inserting into tables but I need to load 1 record as insert and second one needs to update the first record DESCRIPTION to "UPDATE THE RECORD"

Comment: AWS Glue crawler just read the physical files and based on the file schema create table(s). In your case, you are collecting the CDC records. So the two records are generated by CDC, not the Glue. Glue has no idea that one record is an update of the same inserted record. This is an ELT process, you Extract CDC record, Load them into a physical file, now you could Transform to a new table which you could write your own script to merge the expected records.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the issue. It's true Glue is treat every row as a new record. My requirement is get the data from source to s3 location from there I have to generate internal IDs and load to target. The AWS DMS is not supporting to generate the sequence or call from the target database. Now I am planing to do from s3 to s3  using glue to generate IDs and using DMS to load initial and CDC into target.

Comment: Please advice if you have any better approach.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestions.